# Passing date to Stored Procedure in Oracle SQL error : ORA-01858

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I know this question has been answered previously, and I have tried out the solution given in them without success.

I have a stored procedure as below(I have removed non-essential parts) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_days(dt date)
IS
  given_date DATE := TO_DATE('dt', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
BEGIN
  get_day := RTRIM(TO_CHAR(dt1, 'DAY'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The day of the given date is '||get_day||);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Execution  done successfully.');
END get_days;
```

I am having trouble with passing date to the procedure `get_days`. I have tried in the following ways :

```
BEGIN
  --Below I have listed all ways I have tried 
  get_days('12/12/12');
  get_days('12-12-12');
  get_days(date '2012-12-12');  
  get_days(TO_DATE( '01/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ));
END;
```

I don't know what is wrong but I am getting this error - `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`. I have searched for similar errors online but none helped. I am using **Oracle Database 11g Express edition**. There is probably some minor error in my code but I am not getting what it is.

Any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: In TO_DATE( **'dt'**, 'DD-MON-YYYY'); `'dt'` is a string. But why do you want to pass a DATE to TO_DATE?

Comment: dt might be passed in any format. I am just converting it into `DD-MM-YYYY` format and storing into `given_date`

Comment: Well, you defined dt as `date`, thus it has no format. A format is for display only. Btw, the best and shortest way to write a date is a Standard SQL *date literal*: `date '2012-12-12'`

Comment: No, you've declared the formal argument as `dt date` - so its data type is date. It doesn't have any intrinsic human-readable format. The caller has to pass an actual date (if it passes a string and relies on implicit conversion that will go wrong at some point). Even if you has `to_date(dt, ...` without the quotes, instead of `to_date('dt', ....`, you would then be doing your own implicit conversion, which will also break. You should not use something that is *already a date* as the first argument to `to_date()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is that you have

```
  given_date DATE := TO_DATE('dt', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

instead of

```
  given_date DATE := TO_DATE(dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

In your version you are trying to convert the string literal `'dt'` to a date; that literal has no relationship to your `dt` argument.

However, this is still wrong, as `dt` is declared as a date datatype already. If you do that then you are really doing:

```
  given_date DATE := TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(dt), 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

which will use your current session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to convert the date to a string; if that isn't 'DD-MON-YYYY' too (or something close enough that Oracle will [fudge it](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5)) then you will still get an error or, worse, incorrect conversion and invalid results that you might not notice.

So remove that redundant and dangerous conversion:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_days(dt date)
IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The day of the given date is ' || TO_CHAR(dt, 'FMDAY') || '.');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Execution  done successfully.');
END get_days;
/
```

You can of course assign the day name to a string variable if you want. I've used [the `FM` format modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA) to stop it right-padding the day name, so you don't need to trim it - the full-stop is just there to demonstrate that works. If you want the day name in mixed case you can use `'FMDay'` instead of `'FMDAY'`.

You should always pass in a date, not a string:

```
set serveroutput on;

BEGIN
  get_days(date '2012-12-12');  
  get_days(TO_DATE( '01/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ));
END;
/

The day of the given date is WEDNESDAY.
Execution  done successfully.
The day of the given date is MONDAY.
Execution  done successfully.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

> dt might be passed in any format. I am just converting it into DD-MM-YYYY format and storing into given_date

A date doesn't have a format; it has an internal representation which you very rarely need to know or care about. When you query a date value without explicitly converting it to a string, your client converts that to a human-readable form, usually using `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to decide what format to display it in. So `dt` does not have a format, and even if the caller makes the call with a string (as in your first two examples) those will be implicit converted to a date - assuming that's possible - before the call; the procedure will never see those strings, it will only see the converted date value.

Comment: Thanks alex! Your code works for me. I though dates are stored in a particular format that they are assigned which is why I went through converting the `dt` to required format. But that doesn't seems to be the case so, am I right?

Comment: You mentioned in your answer about just passing a date and not a string. But the answer is working for me for Dates as well as when you pass a string like - `get_days('12/12/2012');`

Comment: @Abhishek - see my update based on an earlier comment. `get_days('12/12/2012')` is really doing `get_days(to_date('12/12/2012'))`, so it's relying on that string matching your current session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. Try something like `get_days('2012-12-12')` - that will throw something like ORA-01861, but notice that it's reported against your anonymous block, *not* from the procedure.

Comment: Yep, that answers all my doubts. Thanks for the detailed answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am providing the best answer  to solve the query regarding this program. you can also check it by running by your own

```
DECLARE

dt1 DATE := TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('19/03/2021'), 'DD-MM-YYYY');

get_day VARCHAR2(15);

BEGIN
get_day := RTRIM(TO_CHAR(dt1, 'DAY'));

IF get_day IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') THEN
dbms_output.new_line;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE 
('The day of the given date is '||get_day||' and it falls on weekend');

ELSE
dbms_output.new_line;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The day of the given date is '||get_day||' and it does not fall 
on the weekend');

END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Execution  done successfully.');
END;
```

If you have any further query related to this please ask me, i will try to solve your query as soon as possible.
**IF ANYONE WANT TO INPUT THE DATE BY USER ,PLEASE ASK TO ME....I ALSO HAVE CODE FOR THIS.**